# Context memory leakage in android

Tags: android, performance

I have serious issue of memory leakage in code .The leakage is due to passing context in to progress bar.I have found these using debugging steps in android studio.

This is in login activity

```
AppConstants.showProgress(LoginActivity.this, "Loading");
```

This is in separate class

```
 public static ProgressDialog progressBar;

  public static void showProgress(Context context, String message) {

        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressBar.setMessage(message + "...");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressBar.setCancelable(false);
        progressBar.show();
    }
```

This is the code that produce leakage issues.How to fix this ?

I fix by this way is this correct approach?

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        AppConstants.progressBar=null;
    }
```

Comment: instead of making progress bar and its method static you should declare this method in base activity and access from there.

Comment: public static ProgressDialog progressBar this is the cause for leakage i know. I hide the progress bar using this code  AppConstants.hideProgress();.  My question is to fix without removing static .any way to fix this.

Comment: the only way, you want to keep global reference to dialog and static mechanism of working with it, is to release reference, when you stop, for example, your activity, where dialog was created, thus you will release strong reference to it, and garbage collector will able to destroy it.

Comment: public static void hideProgress() {
        progressBar.hide();
    }                                                                                                                            How to release the resource .Here is the method to hide progress bar .any code to release the resource?

Comment: @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        AppConstants.progressBar=null;
    }                                                                                                                      I fix by this way is this correct approach?